# iOS measuring web page loading time

Tags: ios

I searched a lot but couldn't find the way to measure web page loading time with iOS.
In the app, I want to show certain page loading time.. Is it possible with iOS sdk or third party sdk?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load a URL request and use NSDate to see how long it took...lets assume you use a UIWebView to show your page so to measure the loading time i would capture the time when the URL is requested and then in the delegate methods - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView capture the time again and take the difference, for example

```
//lets say this is where you load the request and you already have your webview set up with a delegate

    -(void)loadRequest
    {
       [webView loadRequest:yourRequest];


       startDate=[NSDate date]
}
//this is the delegate call back for UIWebView
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   NSDate *endDate=[NSDate date];
   double ellapsedSeconds= [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
}
```

If you want to do this without the UIWebView you can just use NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection... you can do the following (I will do it synchrnosly you can also do it async)

```
    NSDate *start=[NSDate date];
    NSURLRequest *r= [[ [NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease]; 
    NSData *response=   [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:r returningResponse:nil error:nil];
   NSDate *end=[NSDate date];
 double ellapsedSeconds= [start timeIntervalSinceDate:end];
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for even providing me good example code... I don't want to show the web page.. just want to check that pages loading time behind the scene.. Just want to show Loading... message while checking the loading time.. Any other way to do it?

Comment: Clean and Easy..Awesome..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with a `UIWebView`, you can set its `delegate` and make note of the time in the delegate's `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` method. The difference between this time and the earlier call to webview's `-loadRequest:` method should give you the loading time.

Comment: Thanks Chaitanya... I am just trying to show some pages loading time without UIWebView.. So screen will show only each pages loading time for kind of network monitoring purpose.. Not easy to find some best way... :(

Comment: Will, to do this you can just use NSURLRequest and issue the request and do the exact same thing, check out my answer below

Comment: Never mind (my now deleted comment). Got what you are trying to say.

Comment: Daniel, I believe `NSURLRequest` is a fetches data synchronously. I would rather suggest using `NSURLConnection` for this.

Comment: You can issue NSURLRequest async as well, one uses NSURLCOnnection to issue the request, just for simplicity I made the sample sync

Comment: Awesome Daniel and Chaitanya..I will try both ways..just started working on iOS..a lot of things to catch up :)