# How can I measure pageload time on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, time, safari, pageload, measure

I am following these pages to live stream video files to my iPhone.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW1

http://techblog.unwiredappeal.com/2010/03/vlc-http-live-streaming-module-patch.html

You know: from mp4 make .ts and .m3u8 file, use video tag pointed to .m3u8 to play the file. Now I need to measure the .m3u8 files and .ts files loading time (in millisecond).

Comment: what about this earlier thread?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210811/ios-measuring-web-page-loading-time

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `UIWebView` delegates and measure the time when the load starts, to when it stops.

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
```