# iOS measuring web page Download TIme

Tags: objective-c, ios

I searched a lot but couldn't find the way to measure web page loading time with iOS. I want to develope an app which opens websites/URL in browser/Safari and gives the Page Load Time. Can you please help me with this.

I also found one of your answer [iOS measuring web page loading time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210811/ios-measuring-web-page-loading-time) , but can please tell wether this will open URL in browser and calculate the Load tie

Answer (score 1):

there is no clean nice completely accurate way of doing this..  try this link.  I think it explains what you're looking for a little more thoroughly.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest

per the author

> ASIWebPageRequests do not currently support progress tracking for an
>   entire request with its external resources. However, progress updates
>   from external resource requests are passed on to your delegate, so
>   with a bit of work it may be possible to implement this yourself.

per the delegate you may use these two events.  I use them to impliment a simple spinner while loading then remove after completion.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)view

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)view
```

Comment: The Above answer Looks good to me, and I can try that way to see if I can get my job done. Another thing I thought of was, can i do it like this, when i Request for a page I will start a timer and as soon as the Page get loaded completely I will get a calback from WebPage or may be browser and will stop the timer and take out the difference to get Page Load time. But here the thing is to  get some CallBack Event or onload Event which can notify about the Page Load Complete. Is there any way to get that?

Comment: adding to answer further explanation, btw if answer works accept it.

Comment: Hi everyone, I need some help. I have made an app and at the end of the app I get csv file as a result. I want to upload that file to the server whose username and password is known to me. can any1 tell me what is the wat to do this. Can i do a SCP or FTP from the xcode application? PLease do help